# What's the best practises to test a Class with JUnit

Tags: java, junit

I'm new to Java, and I recently learn that JUnit is a good tool to test my classes.

I built one class called Person:

```
public Person {
    private String personName;
    private String personID;

    public Person(String personName, String personID){
            this.personName = personName;
            this.personID = personID;
    }

    /* Getters and setters */
}
```

And I built a class that receives a .bat file full of persons, and their informations just like this:

```
1, Carl 
2, Jonh
...
```

And I'm reading that file, line by line, and creating instances:

```
public Person importPerson(String line) {
    String[] splitPersons = line.split(", ");
    int personID = Integer.valueOf(splitPersons[0]);
    String personName = splitPerson[1];
    Person newPerson = new Person(personID, personName);
    return newPerson;
}
```

Now I would like to test my importPerson using JUnit. I built a method for that, but I'm not sure if this test makes all necessary validations.

What should I change on my code to optimize my validations?

```
@Test
public void testImportPerson() {
    String line = "1, Carl";
    Person test = personsGestor.importPerson(line);
    assertEquals("Error inserting ID", 1, test.getPersonID());
    assertEquals("Error inserting Name", "Carl", test.getPersonName());
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Looks pretty good to me. I wouldn't change that unit test.

Comment: Side note: Make `importPerson()` static, you shouldn't need a `Person` object when trying to build a new one from an imported string.

Answer (score 1):

Your test is a happy path testing. Try to add some negative testing as well. For example, what if the line is not parsable in the way your method is expecting? What if it does not have id first etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest unit testing the following conditions:

- Empty line
- Line with a comma only
- Line with >1 commas only
- Line with 1 integer value
- Line with 1 non integer value
- Line with >2 values
- Line with 2 values where first value is not an integer

Answer (score 0):

What are you testing anyway?

If you look at that `Person` class, I'd say it's hardly worth testing: it only has getters and setters (including the constructor), but no real logic / behavior. I'd focus my tests on behavior. Of course you can mess up setters and getters as well, so add a test if you feel like it.

That `importPerson` class has much more functionality. Is that part of the production code? Then by all means write tests for it. I'd try the happy path (like you already did), and various error conditions: no first name, no last name, no comma, names with comma (if that makes sense), invalid files (permission denied).

If `importPerson` is part of your test setup, your test is way too complicated --- it would be much more complicated than the code under test! Drop the external file. It's always bad to have external dependencies like file systems, network, or databases) in unit tests, you'd usually [mock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) them, to make your tests more reliable and less brittle.

That said, you should look into [test-driven development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development), which will guide development with tests and automatically the question of what you should test.